# JSON response comparison and needs result separately for each item

Tags: karate

I have 2 json file response to compare. Below is a sample but the one I need to verify is huge.

1. There is one primary key- "S_Object_ID": I need to get the difference for each item block separately BASED ON "S_Object_ID":
2. The order of the items is different but I need to get the comparison result.
3. There is sub item blocks having primary key - **Sequence_Number** that too needs to be verified
4. Some item may be missing in json file 1 or some in json file2 ...Need to find that too

What is the best way to do this in karate

**json FILE- 1**

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "Delivery_Item": "Y",
            "S_Object_ID": **"1002",**
            "Sweetener_Group": "N/A",
            "DMB_Item": "N"
        },
        {
            "Delivery_Item": "Y",
            "S_Object_ID": "1007",
            "Sweetener_Group": "N/A",
            "DMB_Item": "N"
        },
        {
            "Delivery_Item": "Y",
            "S_Object_ID": "101000001",
            "Sweetener_Group": [
                {
                    "Min_Qty": "0",
                    "Pricing_Level": "N/A",
                    "Sequence_Number": "1",
                    "LTO": "-",
                    "Default_Quantity_XL": "N/A",
                    "Group": "Sweetener_1",
                    "Default_Quantity_L": "N/A",
                    "S_Object_Item_ID": "-",
                    "Max_Qty": "1",
                    "Regional": "N/A"
                },
                {
                    "Min_Qty": "0",
                    "Pricing_Level": "N/A",
                    "Sequence_Number": "2",
                    "LTO": "-",
                    "Default_Quantity_XL": "5",
                    "Group": "Sweetener_1",
                    "Default_Quantity_L": "4",
                    "S_Object_Item_ID": "102003004",
                    "Max_Qty": "10",
                    "Regional": "5"
                }
            ],
            "DMB_Item": "N"
        }

    ],
    "Count": 3
}
```

**json FILE -2**

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "Delivery_Item": "N",
            "S_Object_ID": "1007",
            "Sweetener_Group": "N/A",
            "DMB_Item": "N"
        },
                {
            "Delivery_Item": "Y",
            "S_Object_ID": **"1002",**
            "Sweetener_Group": "N/A",
            "DMB_Item": "N"
        },
        {
            "Delivery_Item": "Y",
            "S_Object_ID": "101000001",
            "Sweetener_Group": [
                {
                    "Min_Qty": "5",
                    "Pricing_Level": "N/A",
                    "Sequence_Number": "1",
                    "LTO": "-",
                    "Default_Quantity_XL": "N/A",
                    "Group": "Sweetener_1",
                    "Default_Quantity_L": "N/A",
                    "S_Object_Item_ID": "-",
                    "Max_Qty": "1",
                    "Regional": "N/A"
                }
            ],
            "DMB_Item": "N"
        },
        {
            "Delivery_Item": "Y",
            "S_Object_ID": "101000002",
            "Sweetener_Group": "N/A",
            "DMB_Item": "N"
        }   

    ],
    "Count": 4
}
```

Comment: linked answer should answer all your questions. next time keep your question specific with short examples: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask